# How do I get LineBreakMode to work in UITableViewCell? iOS - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a header and a body inside my tableviewcells.  I'm trying to get the body to wrap but I'm having issues.

This is the code I'm using in my view controller

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mainCell") as? mainCell {

        cell.mainHeader.text = (mainHeader[indexPath.row])
        cell.mainBody.text = (mainBody[indexPath.row])
        cell.mainBody.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.mainBody.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping


        return cell

    } else {

        return mainCell()
    }

}    

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return mainHeader.count
}


}
```

I searched and thought that the numberOfLines = 0 and lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode would work but it's obviously not.

Sorry if this is simple, thanks in advance.

@Daven

I know this probably won't help, but I don't think I have that or if I do I'm unsure of what it is.  Also updated original code with everything that is in my VC but the vars

I have this for my custom cell

```
import UIKit

class mainCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var mainHeader: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var mainBody: UILabel!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

func configureCell (text:String) {
    mainHeader.text = text
    mainBody.text = text

}


}
```

Comment: Could you post more of your datasource/delegate. Specifically your heightForRowAtIndexPath method, it may help :)

Comment: Edited OP - Sorry if it's not a lot of help

Comment: You said you posted your whole ViewController code - don't you have a heightForRowAtIndexPath method?  I'm guessing the problem is that you're returning a fixed height, so the cell does not expand when it needs to

Comment: Left off the bottom part but still no heightForRowAtIndexPath.  So I need to add that with the proper code inside?

Comment: No need to add that method then.  If you don't set rowHeight of the tableView, try setting the `tableView.estimatedRowHeight` to some value (say `100`, whatever the average height could be).  If you want your cell to grow with different text lengths, your custom cell class should also use autolayout and have the correct constraints

Comment: Ok cool.  Gonna see what I can do.  Thank you for your help

Comment: Not a problem!  I've added an answer below with some more help and a link to a tutorial that I used.  If it helps, please mark it as the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your cell expand as its label grows, you'll need to make sure you've done a few things.  Set your `tableView`'s `estimatedRowHeight` to a value, like

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200.0;
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

or via this method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 200.00
}
```

You also have the option of using this method, but it's not necessary if all your cells are going to vary in height:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

You may also find [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift) helpful (this is what I used :)).  It shows what your autolayout constraints should look like.  More information about self-sizing cells is also [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want your cell to expand when the text is longer than one line, you want to set the cell height to be automatic using the delegate function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

and set the estimated row height using

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return currentInfoSelectorOption.rowHeight + 100
}
```

Then use autolayout in your cell to set the height. You can do this by setting the top and bottom distance constraints of the cell to the label as a constant value and setting the labels number of lines to 0. This should allow the label to expand and push the cell with it